# could this ode be solved by power series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, frobenius-method

I am finding this ode can't be solved by power series. Maple can't solve it either. To find why, I solved it by hand.

Here is my hand solution. Did I do something wrong, or is this all correct, and is the following why Maple can't also solve it?

\begin{align*}
x^{2}y^{\prime\prime}+xy^{\prime}+xy  & =1\\
y^{\prime\prime}+p\left(  x\right)  y^{\prime}+q\left(  x\right)  y  & =1
\end{align*}

Expansion around $x=0$. This is regular singular point. Hence Frobenius is
needed. Therefore $p=\frac{x}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}{x},q=\frac{x}{x^{2}}=\frac{1}
{x}$ and
$$
p_{0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}xp\left(  x\right)  =\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x\frac
{1}{x}=1
$$
And
$$
q_{0}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}x^{2}q\left(  x\right)  =\lim_{x\rightarrow0}
x^{2}\frac{1}{x}=0
$$
Hence the indicial equation is
\begin{align*}
r\left(  r-1\right)  +p_{0}r+q_{0} &  =0\\
r\left(  r-1\right)  +r &  =0\\
r^{2} &  =0
\end{align*}
Hence $r_{1}=0,r_{2}=0$.  Since roots are repeated, then

$$
y=c_{1}y_{1}+c_{2}y_{2}
$$

Where

$$
y_{1}=x^{r_{1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}%
$$

And

$$
y_{2}=y_{1}\ln\left(  x\right)  +x^{r_{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}
$$

Now let

\begin{align}
y &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+r}\nonumber\\
y^{\prime} &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+r\right)  a_{n}x^{n+r-1}
\nonumber\\
y^{\prime\prime} &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(  n+r\right)  \left(
n+r-1\right)  a_{n}x^{n+r-2}\tag{1}
\end{align}
For $r=0$ the above becomes
\begin{align}
y_{1} &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}\nonumber\\
y_{1}^{\prime} &  =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}x^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
na_{n}x^{n-1}\nonumber\\
y_{1}^{\prime\prime} &  =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\left(  n-1\right)  a_{n}
x^{n-2}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n\left(  n-1\right)  a_{n}x^{n-2}\tag{2}
\end{align}
Solve for $y_{1}$ first. Hence the ode becomes
\begin{align*}
x^{2}y_{1}^{\prime\prime}+xy_{1}^{\prime}+xy_{1} &  =1\\
x^{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n\left(  n-1\right)  a_{n}x^{n-2}+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty
}na_{n}x^{n-1}+x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} &  =1\\
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n\left(  n-1\right)  a_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
na_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n+1} &  =1\\
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}n\left(  n-1\right)  a_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
na_{n}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n} &  =1
\end{align*}

Since sums starts at $n=1$ then not possible to match the RHS which is $x^{0}$
as there is no $x^{0}$ in the LHS. Hence no solution exist.

Is the above the reason why this ode can't be solved using power series? If you think this can be solved using power series, then how?

```
restart;
ode:=x^2*diff(y(x),x$2)+x*diff(y(x),x)+x*y(x)=1;
sol:=dsolve(ode,y(x),'series');
```

[image]

Comment: $y_1$ is a basis solution for the homogeneous differential equation. You are allowed to think $a_k=0$ for $k<0$. Then as required $a_0$ is free, $a_1=-a_0$, $4a_2=-a_1=a_0$ etc.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I understand that $a_0$ will be arbitrary. But how does what you say resolves the issue I showed, where there is no balance? How would you continue from where I stopped for example? If I start the sum from $n=1$ then it is as if the RHS was zero or any other constant value, it will never balance and never comes into play, since it is $x^0$ and hence no match and it gets skipped. This is my question. If you know a solution in series for this, will be nice to see it.

Comment: You are matching for the wrong equation. For the basis solutions there is no right side, their equation is *homogeneous*.

Comment: @LutzLehmann how else will you then find the particular solution using series method?? This is how we always did it. It is only this one example where it did not work.  If I change the RHS to $x$ for example, it works, since it will balance. Could you then show how to solve this then using series method? I am not looking for variation of parameters nor undertemined coeff. But using series method only to find $y_h$ and $y_p$?

Comment: You get the full solution via variation of constants, as always. But that includes the second basis solution. If you want to go direct to the solution power series, you need to include the logarithmic terms in the power series ansatz, $y=\sum (a_n+b_n\ln x)x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Maple does solve $x^2 y'' + x y' + x y = 1$, obtaining
$$ y \! \left(x \right) = 
c_1 J_{0}\! \left(2 \sqrt{x}\right) +c_2 Y_{0}\! \left(2 \sqrt{x}\right) -\left(-J_{0}\! \left(2 \sqrt{x}\right) \mathit{MeijerG} \! \left(\left[\left[\;\right], \left[-\frac{1}{2}, 1\right]\right], \left[\left[0, 0, 0\right], \left[-\frac{1}{2}\right]\right], x\right)+Y_{0}\! \left(2 \sqrt{x}\right) \left(x\; {}_{2}^{}{{{F_{3}^{}}}}\! \left(1,1;2,2,2;-x \right)-2 \gamma -\ln \! \left(x \right)\right)\right) \pi
$$
However, it can't expand this MeijerG function in a series about $x=0$.
I suspect there is no series solution for this inhomogeneous differential equation.

EDIT: Sorry, I take that back.  You can use the method of Variation of Parameters to get a particular solution $y_p = u_1 y_1 + u_2 y_2$ where
$$ \eqalign{y_1 &= Y_0(2 \sqrt{x}) \cr
            y_2 &= J_0(2 \sqrt{x}) \cr
            u_1 &= - \int \frac{y_2\; dx}{x^2 W(y_1,y_2)}\cr
            u_2 &= \int \frac{y_1 \; dx}{x^2 W(y_1, y_2)}\cr
            W(y_1,y_2) &= y_1 y_2' - y_1' y_2}$$
Maple will find series expansions for $u_1$ and $u_2$:
$$\eqalign{ u_1 &= \pi  \ln \! \left(x \right)-\pi  x +\frac{1}{8} \pi  \,x^{2}-\frac{1}{108} \pi  \,x^{3}+\frac{1}{2304} \pi  \,x^{4}-\frac{1}{72000} \pi  \,x^{5}+\mathrm{O}\! \left(x^{6}\right)\cr
  u_2 &= -\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{2}-2 \ln \! \left(x \right) \gamma +\left(2 \gamma +\ln \! \left(x \right)-3\right) x +\left(-\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)}{8}+\frac{7}{16}-\frac{\gamma}{4}\right) x^{2}+\left(\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)}{108}-\frac{1}{27}+\frac{\gamma}{54}\right) x^{3}+\left(-\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)}{2304}+\frac{53}{27648}-\frac{\gamma}{1152}\right) x^{4}+\left(\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)}{72000}-\frac{143}{2160000}+\frac{\gamma}{36000}\right) x^{5}+\mathrm{O}\! \left(x^{6}\right)\cr}$$
so that
$$ y_p = \frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{2}+\left(-\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{2}+2 \ln \! \left(x \right)-3\right) x +\left(\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{8}-\frac{3 \ln \! \left(x \right)}{4}+\frac{23}{16}\right) x^{2}+\left(-\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{72}+\frac{11 \ln \! \left(x \right)}{108}-\frac{97}{432}\right) x^{3}+\left(\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{1152}-\frac{25 \ln \! \left(x \right)}{3456}+\frac{485}{27648}\right) x^{4}+\left(-\frac{\ln \! \left(x \right)^{2}}{28800}+\frac{137 \ln \! \left(x \right)}{432000}-\frac{14269}{17280000}\right) x^{5}+\mathrm{O}\! \left(x^{6}\right)
$$
For some reason, Maple won't compute a series for $u_1 y_1$ directly, but you can find the series for $u_1$ and for $y_1$ separately and then multiply them together, similarly for $u_2 y_2$.

EDIT: Actually, of course, the $O(x^6)$ should be $O(\ln(x)^2 x^6)$.

Comment: **I suspect there is no series solution for this inhomogeneous differential equation.** Yes, but I'd like to know why and if the reason I show is why there is no series solution.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. But that is not really what I am asking. I know particular solution can be found by variation of parameters. But this is series method. particular solution comes out from the series method itself. I know Maple can solve by series the ode $x^2 y''+x y'+xy = 0$. And I know how to do that also myself. My question is if the reason why there is no solution by series when RHS is one, is what I showed or not. When using series method, variation of parameter nor method of undetermined coefficient are used. particular solution comes out directly from series method itself.

Comment: Once you know to look for a series of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(a_n + b_n \ln(x) + c_n \ln(x)^2\right)) x^n$, you can solve for the coefficients $a_n$, $b_n$, $c_n$.

Comment: These should satisfy the recurrences $$\eqalign{n^2 a_n + 2nb_n + 2 c_n + a_{n-1} &= 0,\cr n^2 b_n + 4 n c_n + b_{n-1} &= 0\cr
n^2 c_n + c_{n-1} &= 0\cr}$$ for $n \ge 1$, with $a_0 = 0$, $b_0 = 0$, $c_0 = 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

For $$x^2 y'' + x y' + x y = 1$$ Mathematica returns
$$y=c_1 J_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)+ c_2
   Y_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)+$$
$$\pi  J_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)
   G_{2,4}^{3,0}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{1}{2},1 \\
 0,0,0,-\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)-\pi  Y_0\left(2 \sqrt{x}\right)
   G_{1,3}^{2,0}\left(x\left|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 0,0,0 \\
\end{array}
\right.\right)$$

Writing
$$y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\,x^n$$ the first coefficients are
$$\color{red}{a_0}=\frac{1}{2} \log (x) \left(\log (x)+4 \gamma +\frac{2
   c_2}{\pi }\right)+\frac{\pi ^2}{3}+c_1+\frac{2
   \gamma  (\gamma  \pi +c_2)}{\pi }$$
$$6\pi \color{red}{a_1}=-3 \log (x) (\pi  \log (x)+4 (\gamma -1) \pi +2 c_2)-$$ $$2
   \pi  \left(\pi ^2+6 (\gamma -2) \gamma +9+3
   c_1\right)-12 (\gamma -1) c_2$$
$$48\pi \color{red}{a_2}=6 \log (x) (\pi  \log (x)+4 \gamma  \pi -6 \pi +2
   c_2)+4 \pi ^3+$$ $$3 \pi  (8 (\gamma -3) \gamma +23+4
   c_1)+12 (2 \gamma -3) c_2$$
$$432\pi \color{red}{a_3}=-2 \log (x) (3 \pi  \log (x)+2 (6 \gamma -11) \pi +6
   c_2)-$$ $$\pi  \left(4 \pi ^2+8 \gamma  (3 \gamma
   -11)+97+12 c_1\right)-4 (6 \gamma -11) c_2$$
$$27648\pi \color{red}{a_4}=8 \log (x) (3 \pi  \log (x)+(12 \gamma -25) \pi +6
   c_2)+16 \pi ^3+$$ $$\pi  (16 \gamma  (6 \gamma
   -25)+485+48 c_1)+8 (12 \gamma -25) c_2$$
$$17280000\pi \color{red}{a_5}=-40 \log (x) (15 \pi  \log (x)+(60 \gamma -137) \pi
   +30 c_2)-$$ $$\pi  \left(400 \pi ^2+80 \gamma  (30
   \gamma -137)+14269+1200 c_1\right)-40 (60 \gamma
   -137) c_2$$
$$1866240000\pi \color{red}{a_6}=360 \log (x) (5 \pi  \log (x)+(20 \gamma -49) \pi +10
   c_2)+$$ $$1200 \pi ^3+\pi  (720 \gamma  (10 \gamma
   -49)+48587+3600 c_1)+360 (20 \gamma -49) c_2$$